# how to control the simulation speed of d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am following a d3 force laytout example like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953).

I want to control the speed of the dots flying to the cluster. In other words, I want some dots take more time to get to their final positions, while some dots take less time.

I tried to add a timer function to control the time of each tick, but it did not work.

```
this.force = d3.layout.force()
.on("tick", setTimeout(tick(d), 50));
```

I need help for this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set a timer to call the `tick` function, this is done automatically by the force layout.

There are however a number of parameters you can set to modify the behaviour of the force layout. The ones most relevant to what you're trying to do are the following.

1. [`.friction()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-friction) corresponds to how quickly the velocity decays and therefore directly controls how fast nodes move. The default is 0.9, to make everything slower, set it to a lower value.
2. [`.charge()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-charge) controls how strong the attraction/repulsion between nodes is. This doesn't control the velocity directly, but affects it.

Of these parameters, only the latter can be set on a node-by-node basis. This makes achieving what you want a bit tricky, as you would have to carefully balance the forces. As a start, setting the charge of the nodes that you want to move slower closer to 0 should help.

There are a few other parameters of the force layout that I think would not be useful in your particular case (I'm thinking of [`.linkStrength()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkStrength) and [`.linkDistance()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkDistance)), but you may want to have a look nevertheless.

Comment: Yes I need to set the velocity node-by-node. Is it possible to add a "delay" function to each tick iteration? I know it is possible to manually call tick function:                            "force.start();
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) force.tick();
force.stop();"

Comment: Not without hacking the force layout.

Comment: I came to a possible solution. I can just manually call tick function for each node, say 100 times, and record the path. Then I use a timer function to redraw the node according to the path. In this way, I can control the time of drawing for each node. Does this make sense?

Comment: The tick handler is global. The only thing you could do is to ignore the event for certain nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I came to a possible solution. I can just manually call tick function for each node, say 100 times, and record the path. Then I use a timer function to redraw the node according to the path. In this way, I can control the time of drawing for each node. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `setIntervel` function , intervel timing

Try this code:

**[Fiddle:](http://fiddle.jshell.net/manojmcet/udezM/)**

```
 setInterval(function(){
  nodes.push({id: ~~(Math.random() * foci.length)});
  force.start();
  node = node.data(nodes);
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.id); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.id)).darker(2); })
      .call(force.drag);
}, 50); //change the intervel time
```

Comment: Thanks! But your code only changes the time interval of inserting a new node. If I change the interval to 500, the node still takes 50 to fly to the position, and I need to wait for 450 for another node. Instead, I need to change the velocity of the node. That means each node take 500 to fly to their positions.